# Cant seem to grab an attribute in Selenium [Java]

Tags: java, selenium

I'm trying to automate Amazon Login code grabbing using emails, and I keep getting this in my console instead of the actual value.
Here is the code I'm using:

```
    driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    driver.get("https://getnada.com");
    driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".icon-plus")).click();
    driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".user_name")).clear();
    driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".user_name")).sendKeys(euser[0]);
    driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#domain")).sendKeys(euser[1]);
    driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".button")).click();
    TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(2);
    driver.findElement(By.className("msg_item")).click();
    TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(4);
    WebElement otp = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".otp"));
    String otp2 = otp.getText();
    System.out.println(otp2);
```

and Here the console output im ggetting (The output if from this link: String otp2 = otp.getText();).

Not really sure why I cant grab the code that way.

```
*** Element info: {Using=css selector, value=.otp}
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.W3CHttpResponseCodec.createException(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:187)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.W3CHttpResponseCodec.decode(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:122)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.W3CHttpResponseCodec.decode(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:49)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:158)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:83)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:545)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElement(RemoteWebDriver.java:319)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElementByCssSelector(RemoteWebDriver.java:413)
    at org.openqa.selenium.By$ByCssSelector.findElement(By.java:430)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElement(RemoteWebDriver.java:311)
    at Sele.getCode(Sele.java:88)
    at Sele.main(Sele.java:50)
```

Thats the relevant bit of the HTML code (The message itself)

```js
<body><img width="1" height="1" src="https://www.amazon.com/gp/r.html?C=PEZFBQGDUNSN&amp;M=urn:rtn:msg:20180413074245990875ff91624d9d8bb242b741d0p0na&amp;R=3OQKPPQZZDF2F&amp;T=O&amp;U=https%3A%2F%2Fimages-na.ssl-images-amazon.com%2Fimages%2FG%2F01%2Fnav%2Ftransp.gif&amp;H=KSKZSRSP6P3QSUF8JZBWJ5KWQIMA&amp;ref_=pe_1568390_127719720_opens">
  <table align="center" cellspacing="0" id="container" cellpadding="0">
    <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <table cellspacing="0" id="content" cellpadding="0">
          <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td id="header">
              <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                <tbody>
                <tr>
                  <td width="250" id="logo">
<img src="https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/G/01/x-locale/cs/te/logo._CB152417367_.png" id="amazonLogo">                  </td>
                  <td width="250" id="title" valign="top" align="right"><p></p></td>
                </tr>
                </tbody>
              </table>
            </td>
          </tr>

          <tr>
            <td id="verificationMsg">
              <p>Hello,<br> We noticed that there was an attempt to sign in to your Amazon account. If you were prompted for a verification code, please enter the following to complete your sign-in.</p>
              <p class="otp">521914</p>
            </td>
          </tr>

          <tr>
            <td id="accountSecurity">
              <p>This code will expire in 10 minutes. 
<br><br>
If you did not try to sign in to your account, please change your password immediately by visiting your account settings on Amazon. We also recommend changing password on other non-Amazon websites if you use the same password. 
<br><br>
If you have additional questions about account security, please visit amazon.com/security. 
              </p>
            </td>
          </tr>

          <tr>
            <td id="closing">
              <p>Thanks for visiting Amazon!
              </p>
            </td>
          </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  <img width="1" height="1" src="https://www.amazon.com/gp/r.html?C=PEZFBQGDUNSN&amp;M=urn:rtn:msg:20180413074245990875ff91624d9d8bb242b741d0p0na&amp;R=3OQKPPQZZDF2F&amp;T=E&amp;U=https%3A%2F%2Fimages-na.ssl-images-amazon.com%2Fimages%2FG%2F01%2Fnav%2Ftransp.gif&amp;H=X5XU71AZVGA8LYXBO4DVAEXMCFKA&amp;ref_=pe_1568390_127719720_open">
  

<div id="selenium-highlight"></div></body>
```

Comment: share your relevant HTML code please ?

Comment: Sorry about it, added. @cruisepandey

Answer (score 0):

I am going to offer you an alternative which is going to work for you. Try using the following method to locate the element:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//p[@class='otp']"));
```

Comment: if class is already given then go for cssSelector not for Xpath.

Comment: same error in the console log...
> *** Element info: {Using=xpath, value=//p[@class='otp']}

Answer (score 0):

Here is your **HTML Code :**

```
<html>
<head>
<title>StackOverFlow</title>
</head>
<body>
<tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <table cellspacing="0" id="content" cellpadding="0">
          <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td id="header">
              <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                <tbody>
                <tr>
                  <td width="250" id="logo">
<img src="https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/G/01/x-locale/cs/te/logo._CB152417367_.png" id="amazonLogo">                  </td>
                  <td width="250" id="title" valign="top" align="right"><p></p></td>
                </tr>
                </tbody>
              </table>
            </td>
          </tr>

          <tr>
            <td id="verificationMsg">
              <p>Hello,<br> We noticed that there was an attempt to sign in to your Amazon account. If you were prompted for a verification code, please enter the following to complete your sign-in.</p>
              <p class="otp">521914</p>
            </td>
          </tr>

          <tr>
            <td id="accountSecurity">
              <p>This code will expire in 10 minutes. 
<br><br>
If you did not try to sign in to your account, please change your password immediately by visiting your account settings on Amazon. We also recommend changing password on other non-Amazon websites if you use the same password. 
<br><br>
If you have additional questions about account security, please visit amazon.com/security. 
              </p>
            </td>
          </tr>

          <tr>
            <td id="closing">
              <p>Thanks for visiting Amazon!
              </p>
            </td>
          </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</body>
</html>
```

**Java + Selenium code :**

```
public class StackOverFlow {

    static WebDriver driver;
    static WebDriverWait wait;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
            System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "F:\\Automation\\chromedriver.exe");
            String pathToExtension = "file:/C:/Users/USER_DELL_2014_07/Desktop/NewFolder/def.html";
            driver = new ChromeDriver();
            driver.manage().window().maximize();
            driver.get(pathToExtension);
            WebElement otp = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".otp"));
            String otp2 = otp.getText();
            System.out.println(otp2);
        }
}
```

It's working in my machine.

Comment: Check this two lines in your code :  at Sele.getCode(Sele.java:88)
    at Sele.main(Sele.java:50)

Comment: not really sure whats going on then, im trying to scrape from a temporary email site, site might doing some problems that I cant see with selenium.
Line 50 is just the call for the method, line 88 is the WebElement command.
I've attached the full method cause im not really sure whats going on

Comment: added all the relevant info, im still clueless why it isnt working :X

Comment: what is the scenario that you want to automate on this site (https://getnada.com)? AFAIU : 1. you want to click on Add inbox button 2. you want to provide name . 3. You want to select a domain from drop down 4.You want to click on accept .

Comment: After these steps what do you wanna do ?

Comment: amm I just grabbed the specific email URL from getnada then scraped data from the URL, and it semms to work now.